# Есть ли у NODE JS аналог питоновского Fernet?

Tags: javascript, python

вот пример кода на Python:

```
data = "TEST DATA"
key = 'TEST-ENCODE-KEY'
fernet = Fernet(key)
encdata = fernet.encrypt(data.encode())
```

есть ли в NODE JS фреймворк, который по ключу TEST-ENCODE-KEY зашифрует переменную data точно так же как в питоне?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть npm пакет Fernet для NodeJs https://www.npmjs.com/package/fernet